# Viewport width = device-width is not working

Tags: html, css

I have this angular app, and I want to add a responsive design for mobile version too, right now it looks horrible, I read about `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">` but is not working.

[image]

On my browser or on my phone it looks like that, if I change my phone to horizontal, I can see the page well.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cv</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resumePhoto.png" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

 <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

 <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
 </html>
```

You can find the repository in my [github](https://github.com/Ricardozs/OnlineResumeWeb) or here is the link of the [app](https://ricardosresume.web.app/about/overview).

A funny thing is that if I change the value in the inspector let's say I change the scale from 1 to 1.1 it works, and if I return it to 1 I'll keep working, but at the beginning, it seems to be ignored.

My problem is that it looks chopped, it doesn't matter if a try to scroll to the right I don't see my top navbar.

*Edit*

I tried to add media queries, but I discovered something, my navbar is still there, I just can't see it but I can click on the buttons, and it looks like the header-nav takes more than the width of the device, in the next image you can see that the width is 310 px but the header-nav 520 from clarity takes the value of, perhaps that's why it looks weird, I'm thinking it has something to do with the project clarity classes

[image]

Comment: Do you have element with fixed sizes? like `width: 400px` or things like that? double check that

Comment: @arieljuod I have them in things like images but not in div or anything like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok at the end, I find out the problem was I didn't read the whole documentation for project clarity, their components already have that responsive parts that normally you would do with `@media queries`, but turns out I have to add some properties to them to make them responsive.

In the end, I didn't have to add any `@media queries`, and it wasn't a problem of the `viewport`, I just added the property `[clr-nav-level]="1"` to my header and that fixed it.

```
 <div class="header-nav" [clr-nav-level]="1">
```

Here is the [documentation](https://clarity.design/documentation/navigation#responsive_navigation) in case you want to read it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your line here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes>
```

You need now to add some @media-queries for each size of screen you want your app to work on. You need to add those @media-queries to your css stylesheet so that it adjusts on whatever size. For example:

```
/* iPhone 6+/7+/8+ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 414px) {
// adjust the elements with css
}
```

You can set min-width or min-height or whatever you want to adjust to landscape modes etc.
[More about media queries here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/media_queries)

Comment: but should I change the Html or body width in the `@media-queries`? It's my first time using them

Comment: You should not adjust the width of your body, but adjust every element inside of it (`font-size`, `width` and `height` for example). That's how you should use `@media-queries`. However you can adjust the width of your body if you want but its content will also certainly shrink so that's not a correct way to use `@media-queries`. I hope that helps.

Comment: in the inspector seems that the HTML and body are small, that's why I thought on change them

Comment: Do as you want, it's your website afterall. Anyways I explained how to adapt your site for different sizes. Please mark my answer as solution for future readers.

Comment: so if adjust the size of every element, it won't look chopped up?

Comment: It will look as you want it to look, i'm not sure where you want to go from here…

Comment: I edited the question and change the image, hopefully I made myself clear

Comment: Please read my answer and click the link to learn about media-queries, it seems like you did not understand the concept.